# How do I bind a line chart to the results of a SELECT statement in a Windows Forms Application (C#)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, charts

I'm doing a Windows Forms Application for people suffering from hypertension and on one of the screens, the user should be able to put in two dates into two DateTimePickers and then click a button. The button will then run a stored procedure that queries the database I have set up, which then populates the line chart with the systolic and diastolic readings that are in the database between those two dates, with the X Axis being the date and the Y Axis being the reading.

The query I have is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ViewData]

@PatientID int,
@StartDate date,
@EndDate date
AS
SELECT Systolic, Diastolic FROM Record
WHERE PatientID = @PatientID AND DateTaken BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
RETURN 0
```

So far, @StartDate, @EndDate and @PatientID exist on the application already, but I just don't know how to get the results of the query to appear on the graph in two lines. One for the systolic and one for the diastolic.

I've tried something like:

```
 SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(global::Hypertension.Properties.Settings.Default.HyperDataConnectionString);

         string sqlStr = "EXECUTE sp_ViewData @PatientID, @StartDate, @EndDate";
        SqlDataAdapter myCommand = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, mySqlConnection);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        myCommand.Fill(ds);

        DataView source = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);

        crtData.DataSource = source;

        crtData.Series[0].XValueMember = "DateTaken";
        crtData.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Systolic";
        crtData.Series[1].XValueMember = "DateTaken";
        crtData.Series[1].YValueMembers = "Diastolic";
        crtData.DataBind();
```

But it isn't working for me and I really don't know why.

Is there something I'm missing? I've been trying to find a solution to this problem for a while, and everything I've found has either not been detailed enough (grabbing all the data from a table and not specific data) or not been answered at all.

I'd greatly appreciate it if anybody could help me out, since I'm kinda lost here.

Comment: What about it isn't working? Does anything show up on the chart, do incorrect values show up, etc?

Comment: Looks fine, but if you won't tell us more, we can't help!

Comment: No data shows up at all. Just "Series 1" and nothing else. I also don't know how to format the chart so it's with lines and not with bars.

Comment: `crtData.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;`

Comment: You may use the Debugger to look at the Points to see how many there are and what values they have. If they're all 0 not much will show but the X-axis labels..